# How to Get json.json file From Twitter Embed API in React Native App

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch-api, react-native-fetch-blob, rn-fetch-blob

According to the Twitter docs, in order to embed a twitter video into an app, you have to use their embed endpoint like so: [https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=${enter_twitter_video_url}](https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=$%7Benter_twitter_video_url%7D).

Example: https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=https://twitter.com/infinite_red/status/1507392896739151882

The strange thing about this is that it doesn't act like normal embed links where you get a json response from a fetch call. It actually triggers a json.json download in the browser. Within that file, it contains the embed link. That obviously complicates things from a code perspective. If it just sent a json response using axios or apisauce, it would be easy to parse the response for the embed link. Instead it is actually within a file that you have to download.

I attempted to use rn-fetch-blob to grab this json file, but it grabs empty state html data from the twitter page instead. Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

I've also tried a few out of date libraries that don't work either, as this json download issue must be a newer change from twitter. It used to be an actual json response.

Twitter embed docs:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/guides/oembed-api

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/overview

This has been a full day of struggle, thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encodeURIComponent the link. Then the response will give you clean JSON.

```html
export const getTwitterEmbed = async (tweet_post) => {

    const post_url = tweet_post

    try {
        const response = await fetch(

            `https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=${encodeURIComponent(post_url)}`,
            {
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            }
        )
        const post = await response.json()


        return post

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error
    }
}







[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Thank you! It would appear that since I posted this question, Twitter fixed their oembed API. I had tried exactly what you showed above and did not have success several months ago and it is working now! 

Thank you for responding!